# ¿Como puedo guardar el resultado de una consulta en un array utilizando procedimiento almacenado MySQL?

Tags: mysql, array, stored-procedure

Quiero que al ejecutar esta consulta

```
SELECT tabla1.campo1 
            From tabla1, tabla2 
            Where tabla1.campo1 = tabla2.campo1 
            Group By tabla1.campo1;
```

La cual me dará por ejemplo 600 registros, guardar los 600 registros en un arreglo para posteriormente usar el indice del arreglo (de 1 a 600) como comparación en otra consulta, segun debo usar un arreglo y un ciclo for, pero ya investigue y no encuentro un ejemplo claro, me gustaria saber las siguientes cosas:

Se puede hacer lo que quiero?

Es eficiente en cuanto a recursos?

Existe algún método mejor?

Comment: MySQL no tiene un tipo de dato `ARRAY`. ¿Deseas guardar el resultado de esta consulta en una tabla temporal para usarlo posteriormente?

Comment: Puedes guardarlo como una vista

Comment: @Barranka Sucede que estoy migrando una aplicación web de .asp a php y quizás eso me tiene un poco confundido porque estoy siguiendo el método que utilizaron antes, en si se trata de obtener el campo1 con un Inner Join ese campo1 tiene 600 registros, posteriormente debo hacer otra consulta donde voy a utilizar cada uno de esos registros para hacer una comparación, así que no se si sea buena idea guardar esos 600 registros de un solo campo en una tabla temporal y si es una buena opción como mandaría a traer cada registro posteriormente?

Comment: @Barranka No había visto tu respuesta cuando escribí el comentario anterior me parece buena idea lo que me propones, lo voy a checar, es que la mera verdad es la 1ra vez que utilizo procedimientos almacenados

Comment: Para proponer mejores alternativas, sería bueno conocer cuántas veces más durante esa sesión se va a llamar a este grupo de datos, si es que varía con el tiempo, qué tan rápido varía su contenido, etc. Ahora, por mi experiencia con MySQL, mi primera recomendación es **no** utilizar una vista.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza exactamente este grupo de datos solo 1 vez, pero hay otros 3 grupos de datos que son muy similar solo cambian algunos campos, gracias por la recomendación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque MySQL no posee un tipo de dato `ARRAY`, creo que lo que deseas es utilizar el resultado de tu consulta posteriormente, sin tener que estarla escribiendo una y otra vez. Esto es posible: puedes guardar el resultado en una tabla temporal, y usarlo cuantas veces quieras:

```
-- Cambié el JOIN implícito (tu condición WHERE) por un JOIN explícito, por claridad
create temporary table temp_resultado
    SELECT tabla1.campo1 
    FROM tabla1 INNER JOIN tabla2 ON tabla1.campo1 = tabla2.campo1
    GROUP BY tabla1.campo1;
-- No olvides generar un índice:
ALTER TABLE temp_resultado
    ADD INDEX idx_campo1(campo1);
```

Ahora bien, si lo que necesitas es asignar un número a cada registro, puedes usar variables de usuario:

```
create temporary table temp_resultado
    SELECT @n := @n + 1 as n
         , tabla1.campo1 
    FROM (select @n := 0) as init, (tabla1 INNER JOIN tabla2 ON tabla1.campo1 = tabla2.campo1)
    GROUP BY tabla1.campo1;
-- No olvides generar un índice:
ALTER TABLE temp_resultado
    ADD INDEX idx_campo1(campo1);
```

Recuerda: Las tablas temporales sólo son visibles para la conexión que las crea, y son destruidas una vez que la conexión que las crea es cerrada.

---

**Actualizción**

Como puedes ver, no estoy utilizando un procedimiento almacenado para generar la tabla que requieres, sino que estoy generando "al vuelo" los números de fila que necesitas.

*¿Cómo funciona?*

```
SELECT @n := @n + 1 as n
     , tabla1.campo1 
FROM (select @n := 0) as init
   , (tabla1 INNER JOIN tabla2 ON tabla1.campo1 = tabla2.campo1)
GROUP BY tabla1.campo1;
```

En la cláusula `FROM` incluyo tus dos tablas, y una subconsulta (que llamo `init`) para inicializar la variable `@n`. Recuerda que en SQL el "orden de ejecución" es:

1. `FROM`: El servidor revisa que los orígenes de datos existan y puedan leerse; además, se establecen las relaciones requeridas
2. `WHERE`: Se aplican los filtros pertinentes sobre los orígenes de datos
3. `GROUP BY`: Se agrupan los datos
4. `SELECT`: Se leen los campos y se calculan las expresiones (incluyendo las expresiones de agregación
5. `HAVING`: Se aplican los filtros pertinentes a los datos *después* de haber sido agrupados

Así pues, aprovechando que lo primero que se ejecuta es el `FROM`, pongo ahí una consulta de inicialización de variables (`init`). La variable `@n` se inicializa en cero, y cada vez que el `SELECT` lee una fila, actualiza el valor de `@n`, agregándole 1.

Finalmente, al crear una tabla temporal, garantizas que los números de fila no se actualizan cada vez que ejecutas la consulta (dado que no estás ordenando los valores, no hay garantía de que se respete un orden en las filas).

Una vez que ejecutas las consultas anteriores, puedes usar estos valores sencillamente seleccionando todas las filas de la tabla recién creada:

```
select * from temp_resultado order by n;
```

Ahora bien, veo que no estás utilizando ninguna función de agregación; creo que entonces es más sencillo usar `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
drop table if exists temp_resultado; -- Si existe la tabla, bórrala
create temporary table temp_resultado
    select distinct @n := @n + 1 as n, tabla1.campo1
    from (select @n := 0) as init
       , (tabla1 inner join tabla2 on tabla1.campo1 = tabla2.campo1)
       -- Si el campo que usas para relacionar las tablas tiene el mismo nombre,
       -- puedes usar:
       -- (tabla1 inner join tabla2 using (campo1))
    order by tabla1.campo1; -- Generalmente es prudente especificar 
                            -- el orden de los registros
-- No olvides agregar los índices:
alter table temp_resultado
    add unique index idx_n(n),
    add index idx_campo1(campo1);
-- Muestra el resultado
select * from temp_resultado;
```

---

**¿Por qué es mejor "al vuelo" que con un procedimiento?**

Si deseas probar con un procedimiento almacenado, considera lo siguiente:

1. Necesitas una tabla para guardar los datos
2. Necesitas insertar los datos en esa tabla
3. Necesitas recorrer esa tabla fila por fila para agregar el valor que deseas (aunque podrías usar un valor `AUTO_INCREMENT` en la definición de la tabla, sería deseable que mejor el procedimiento almacenara el número)

Por mera economía de teclas, te conviene generar los valores "al vuelo". Por otra parte, al generar los valores "al vuelo" usando variables temporales, realmente no le estás dando demasiado trabajo extra al servidor.

Comment: Sobre lo de asignar un numero a cada registro, digamos que tengo 600 registros para obtener la variable que utilizare en la comparacion solo debo utilizar `@n` ? y de ser asi aun debo usar un ciclo for o eso ya no es necesario al momento que le asignas `@n + 1 as n` ?

Comment: Ya lo estuve investigando y aun no me queda del todo claro, vamos dame una pista aunque sea jaja

Comment: Por cierto como le asignaría valor a n??

Comment: @GuillermoVargas Checa mi actualización. El valor de `@n` se actualiza al vuelo y se guarda en la tabla temporal.

Comment: muchas gracias esta muy claro ahora solo me falta ver que si funcione, no lo he podido comprobar porque en el proyecto que estoy trabajando resulta que no tengo permisos para utilizar ciertos comandos, en cuanto verifique que me funciono marco la respuesta como solución

Comment: Funciona perfecto muchísimas gracias, tuve que crear otras tablas de manera local para probar, porque no tengo permisos en el servidor donde están las base de datos que estoy utilizando pero al menos ya se que funciona perfecto, ahora solo necesito aclarar eso de los permisos a la hora que llegue el jefe

Comment: Por cierto la ultima pregunta, como seria mas eficiente realizar lo anterior, así como me pusiste el ejemplo generando "al vuelo" o realizar un procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: @GuillermoVargas Checa mi última actualización

Comment: muchas  gracias oye este ejemplo que me pusiste aqui se puede realizar en php o CodeIgniter? Te pregunto porque solo he hecho una consulta a la vez pero no 2 en la cual una dependa de la otra

Comment: Si lo haces en PHP (o cualquier otro lenguaje), ¿para qué necesitas un valor generado por la base de datos? Basta con que leas el resultado de la consulta y vayas guardando los valores en un array; luego recorre el array (cada fila del array está ya numerada por su índice)

Comment: el error fue mio, sucede que es la 1ra vez que trabajo en esto y no tenia idea de como hacerlo ya que me estaba guiando de como lo habían hecho antes(estoy migrando de asp a php) y crei que lo mejor era un procedimiento almacenado, cuando me diste un ejemplo que funciona a la perfección ya no supe como adaptarlo en php, disculpa por no haberme explicado bien